# qt_create works in Fuerte?

Tags: qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Im trying to use Qt as an user interface for a moving robot platform. So trying to integrate it in ROS. Im totally new beginner in QT and pretty advanced in ROS. So I dont know from where to start first?I have created ROS package and all works fine. So now what should I do with QT side?From where to start with QT? I was told to add QT library in my ROS pkg use it like qt.

And when using  http://wiki.ros.org/qt_ros what is the difference when add Qt library to ROS pkg? I found that for qt_create there is no documentation for fuerte.Im using Fuerte version of ROS so means it does not works for Fuerte??

Any help as Im bit lost

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106256/qt_create-works-in-fuerte?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't tell you exactly what to do, but I can point you in the right direction. You need to include Qt header files in your and point to Qt libraries for linking in your build. All of this needs to happen in your CMakeLists.txt file and what you include will depend on the libraries you're attempting to use.

Once you point the ROS build system to the right place, you should be able to use Qt just like you would in a regular C++ project:

```
#include <QTextEdit>
QTextEdit * text = new QTextEdit;
// etc.
```

For CMakeLists-specific syntax, see http://answers.ros.org/question/12790/ros-qt-creator-gui/ and http://answers.ros.org/question/56047/how-should-i-modify-my-cmakelists-file-to-build-a-qt-ros-node/

---

Originally posted by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) with karma: 435 on 2013-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1